Extracted Variables are not writing into the CSV file using Groovy JSR233 Post Processer
I tried the below Groovy code JSR233 Post Procosser , It's reaching to the file path that I ensured by entering the manual text and it's clearing it, but after that it's not writing the extracted values into the file and doesn't throws any error
// Define the path to the CSV file
def csvFilePath = 'C:/xxxxxxxxxxx/testdata/login_landing_access-token_data.csv'
 // Clear the contents of the CSV file without deleting the header
    def csvFile = new File(csvFilePath)
    if (csvFile.exists()) {
        def csvWriter = new FileWriter(csvFilePath)
        def header = 'captured_access_token,captured_userid,captured_user_emailaddress,captured_login_responsebody\n'
        csvWriter.append(header)
        csvWriter.flush()
        csvWriter.close()
    }
    
    // Write extracted values for the current thread only on the first iteration
    if (ctx.getThreadNum() == 0 && ctx.getVariables().getIteration() == 1) {
        def capturedToken = vars.get('captured_access_token')
        def capturedUserid = vars.get('captured_userid')
        def capturedEmailaddress = vars.get('captured_user_emailaddress')
        def capturedResponseBody = vars.get('captured_login_responsebody')
    
        // Write to CSV file
        def csvWriter = new FileWriter(csvFilePath, true)
        csvWriter.append("${capturedToken},${capturedUserid},${capturedEmailaddress},${capturedResponseBody}\n")
        csvWriter.flush()
        csvWriter.close()
        
       
    }

Also tired the Below code Delete the file & Recreate before Test starts
  try {
    // Define the path to the CSV file
    def csvFilePath = "C:/xxxxxxxxx/testdata/login_landing_access-token_data.csv"

    // Delete the file if it exists
    def csvFile = new File(csvFilePath)
    if (csvFile.exists()) {
        csvFile.delete()
    }

    // Recreate the file if it doesn't exist
    if (!csvFile.exists()) {
        csvFile.createNewFile()
        def csvWriter = new FileWriter(csvFilePath, true)
        csvWriter.append("captured_access_token,captured_userid,captured_user_emailaddress,captured_login_responsebody\n")
        csvWriter.close()
    }

    // Write extracted values including headers for the current thread only on the first iteration
    if (ctx.getThreadNum() == 0 && ctx.getVariables().getIteration() == 1) {
        def capturedToken = vars.get("captured_access_token")
        def capturedUserid = vars.get("captured_userid")
        def capturedEmailaddress = vars.get("captured_user_emailaddress")
        def capturedResponseBody = vars.get("captured_login_responsebody")

        // Write to CSV file
        def csvWriter = new FileWriter(csvFilePath, true)

        csvWriter.append("${capturedToken},${capturedUserid},${capturedEmailaddress},${capturedResponseBody}\n")
        csvWriter.flush() // Flush the writer to ensure the data is written immediately
        csvWriter.close()
    }
} catch (Exception e) {
    log.error("Error occurred while writing to CSV file: ${e.message}")
}


If the exists, you create a new one and then conditionally write to it. Can you rule out that not being a logic problem? Have you tried tried not removing the file or appending to it unconditionally?

Yes, I have tried it throws the error  as JMeter Loads the CSV files 1st, That's the reason I went for clear option
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: File login_landing_access-token_data.csv must exist and be readable

I am able to Write the Extracted values into the CSV successfully using Bean Shell Post Processor

Your code looks okayish and it does write the variables values to the CSV file given the variables have their values.
If you amend your code to something like:
vars.put('captured_access_token', 'foo')
vars.put('captured_userid', 'bar')
vars.put('captured_user_emailaddress', 'baz')
vars.put('captured_login_responsebody', 'qux')


// Define the path to the CSV file
def csvFilePath = 'C:/xxxxxxxxxxx/testdata/login_landing_access-token_data.csv'
// Clear the contents of the CSV file without deleting the header
def csvFile = new File(csvFilePath)
if (csvFile.exists()) {
    def csvWriter = new FileWriter(csvFilePath)
    def header = 'captured_access_token,captured_userid,captured_user_emailaddress,captured_login_responsebody\n'
    csvWriter.append(header)
    csvWriter.flush()
    csvWriter.close()
}

// Write extracted values for the current thread only on the first iteration
if (ctx.getThreadNum() == 0 && ctx.getVariables().getIteration() == 1) {
    def capturedToken = vars.get('captured_access_token')
    def capturedUserid = vars.get('captured_userid')
    def capturedEmailaddress = vars.get('captured_user_emailaddress')
    def capturedResponseBody = vars.get('captured_login_responsebody')

    // Write to CSV file
    def csvWriter = new FileWriter(csvFilePath, true)
    csvWriter.append("${capturedToken},${capturedUserid},${capturedEmailaddress},${capturedResponseBody}\n")
    csvWriter.flush()
    csvWriter.close()
}

you will see that the login_landing_access-token_data.csv has the following content:
captured_access_token,captured_userid,captured_user_emailaddress,captured_login_responsebody
foo,bar,baz,qux 

So use Debug Sampler and View Results Tree listener combination to check your variables values, it might be the case your Post-Processor fails somewhere somehow.
Also check jmeter.log file for any suspicious entries

If you are planning to (a) have multiple users write to the same file, or (b) use this data inside of the same test by another user, then the recommended path is to write the data to a queue for processing and not a file.
For (a) you are going to continually fight lock contention and data integrity as multiple agents attempt to write to the same file.  For (b) using a queue ensures that you have FIFO processing and no lock contention as some user fight for locl on update while others want a to read.
All of the major cloud players offer queues at stupid cheap rates, such as the first million messages at no charge.   Or, you can deploy your own internally with a tool such as RabbitMQ.   Avoid implementing queues on the same DB as your system under test as this introduces a load in test that is not present in production.
